# Pandas find common matches between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes and I want to find common matches based on a column (tld), once match has been found, I want to update column match as True.
How to update column in destination dataframe?

**Dataframe 1:** source

```
   uuid           website company_name           tld
0     1  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com
1     2     www.yahoo.com    yahoo inc     yahoo.com
2     3    www.google.com       Google    google.com
3     4     www.cisco.com        Cisco     cisco.com
```

**Dataframe 2:** destination

```
  id  website           company_name           tld  match
0  a  www.facebook.com      facebook  facebook.com  False
1  b         www.y.com     Yahoo Inc         y.com  False
2  c         www.g.com        Google         g.com  False
3  d         www.g.com    Google Inc         g.com  False
4  e  www.facebook.com  Facebook Inc  facebook.com  False
```

Find matches:

`matches = source[source.tld.isin(destination.tld.values)]`

**Matches**

```
0     1  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com
```

**Destination**

```
  id  website           company_name           tld  match
0  a  www.facebook.com      facebook  facebook.com  True
1  b         www.y.com     Yahoo Inc         y.com  False
2  c         www.g.com        Google         g.com  False
3  d         www.g.com    Google Inc         g.com  False
4  e  www.facebook.com  Facebook Inc  facebook.com  True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `isin` to update:

```
df2.loc[df2.tld.isin(df1.tld),'match']=True
df2

Out[669]: 
  id           website company_name           tld  match
0  a  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com   True
1  b         www.y.com     YahooInc         y.com  False
2  c         www.g.com       Google         g.com  False
3  d         www.g.com    GoogleInc         g.com  False
4  e  www.facebook.com  FacebookInc  facebook.com   True
```

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you want:

```
destination["match"] = destination["tld"].isin(source.tld)
```