# Copy column from dataframe after matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes and I found common matches based on a column (tld), once match has been found (between a column in source and destination) I to need to copy the value of column in destination dataframe?

**Dataframe 1: source**

```
   uuid           website company_name           tld
0     11  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com
1     22     www.yahoo.com    yahoo inc     yahoo.com
2     33    www.google.com       Google    google.com
3     44     www.cisco.com        Cisco     cisco.com
```

**Dataframe 2: destination**

```
  id  website           company_name           tld  match uuid
0  a  www.facebook.com      facebook  facebook.com  False  NaN
1  b         www.y.com     Yahoo Inc         y.com  False  NaN
2  c         www.g.com        Google         g.com  False  NaN
3  d         www.g.com    Google Inc         g.com  False  NaN
4  e  www.facebook.com  Facebook Inc  facebook.com  False  NaN
```

Find [matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226423/pandas-find-common-matches-between-2-dataframes/51226499#51226499):

```
destination.loc[destination.tld.isin(source.tld),'match'] = True
```

I need to copy the UUID column from source into the UUID column 
in the destination dataframe.

```
 id           website company_name           tld  match  uuid
0  a  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com   True  11
1  b         www.y.com     YahooInc         y.com  False  NaN
2  c         www.g.com       Google         g.com  False  NaN
3  d         www.g.com    GoogleInc         g.com  False  NaN
4  e  www.facebook.com  FacebookInc  facebook.com   True  11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df2.merge(df1[['tld','uuid']],on='tld',how='left')
Out[677]: 
  id           website company_name           tld  match  uuid
0  a  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com   True   1.0
1  b         www.y.com     YahooInc         y.com  False   NaN
2  c         www.g.com       Google         g.com  False   NaN
3  d         www.g.com    GoogleInc         g.com  False   NaN
4  e  www.facebook.com  FacebookInc  facebook.com   True   1.0
```

Comment: Need to copy the UUID from the source dataframe, in this case facebook.com has uuid 1, in your solution you are hardcoding 1, but could be any value. For example if I match google.com I should assign the UUID (3). Edited for clarity

Comment: @spicyramen using `merge` then