# Pandas merge multiple times generates a _x and _y columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes where I found common matches based on a column (tld), if a match is found (between a column in source and destination) I copied the value of column (uuid) from source to the destination dataframe.

Now I also need to check if a different column is a match. (company_name)

**Dataframe 1: source**

```
   uuid           website company_name           tld
0     11  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com
1     22     www.yahoo.com    yahoo inc     yahoo.com
2     33    www.google.com       Google    google.com
3     44     www.cisco.com        Cisco     cisco.com
```

**Dataframe 2: destination**

```
  id  website           company_name           tld  match uuid
0  a  www.facebook.com      facebook  facebook.com  False  NaN
1  b         www.y.com     Yahoo Inc         y.com  False  NaN
2  c         www.g.com        Google         g.com  False  NaN
3  d         www.g.com    Google Inc         g.com  False  NaN
4  e  www.facebook.com  Facebook Inc  facebook.com  False  NaN
```

Find [matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51226423/pandas-find-common-matches-between-2-dataframes/51226499#51226499):

```
destination.loc[destination.tld.isin(source.tld),'match'] = True
destination = destination.merge(source[['tld', 'uuid']], on='tld', how='left')
```

The above copy the UUID column from source into the UUID column 
in the destination dataframe.

```
 id           website company_name           tld  match  uuid
0  a  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com   True  11
1  b         www.y.com     YahooInc         y.com  False  NaN
2  c         www.g.com       Google         g.com  False  NaN
3  d         www.g.com    GoogleInc         g.com  False  NaN
4  e  www.facebook.com  FacebookInc  facebook.com   True  11
```

Now I need to check if company_name is a match as well to have something like this:

```
 id           website company_name           tld  match  uuid
0  a  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com   True  11
1  b         www.y.com     YahooInc         y.com  False  NaN
2  c         www.g.com       Google         g.com  True   33
3  d         www.g.com    GoogleInc         g.com  False  NaN
4  e  www.facebook.com  FacebookInc  facebook.com   True  11
```

When I try to add:

```
destination.loc[destination.company_name.isin(source.company_name), 'match'] = True
destination = destination.merge(source[['company_name', 'uuid']], on='company_name', how='left')
```

I get a duplicated uuid column: uuid_x and uuid_y

```
id           website  company_name           tld  match uuid_x uuid_y
0  a  www.facebook.com      facebook  facebook.com   True     11     11
1  b         www.y.com     Yahoo Inc         y.com  False    NaN    NaN
2  c         www.g.com        Google         g.com   True    NaN     33
3  d         www.g.com    Google Inc         g.com  False    NaN    NaN
4  e  www.facebook.com  Facebook Inc  facebook.com   True     11    NaN
```

**Final code**

```
destination.loc[destination.tld.isin(source.tld),'match'] = True
destination = destination.merge(source[['tld', 'uuid']], on='tld', how='left')
destination.loc[destination.company_name.isin(source.company_name), 'match'] = True
destination = destination.merge(source[['company_name', 'uuid']], on='company_name', how='left')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need for column `match` chain boolean mask `m1` with `m2` and for new column for matched values [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
m1 = destination.tld.isin(source.tld)
m2 = destination.company_name.isin(source.company_name)
destination['match'] = m1 | m2
destination1 = destination.merge(source[['tld', 'uuid']], on='tld', how='left')
destination = destination.merge(source[['company_name','uuid']],on='company_name',how='left')

destination['uuid'] = destination['uuid'].combine_first(destination1['uuid'])
print (destination)
  id           website  company_name           tld  match  uuid
0  a  www.facebook.com      facebook  facebook.com   True  11.0
1  b         www.y.com     Yahoo Inc         y.com  False   NaN
2  c         www.g.com        Google         g.com   True  33.0
3  d         www.g.com    Google Inc         g.com  False   NaN
4  e  www.facebook.com  Facebook Inc  facebook.com   True  11.0
```